# Find third coordinate of (right) triangle given 2 coordinates and ray to third

Tags: python, algorithm, coordinates, trigonometry

I start explaining my problem from very far, so you could suggest completely different approaches and understand custom objects and functions.
Over years I have recorded many bicycle GPS tracks (.gpx). I decided to merge these (mostly overlapping) tracks into a large graph and merge/remove most of track points. So far, I have managed to simplify tracks (feature in gpxpy module, that removes about 90% of track-points, while preserving positions of corners) and load them into my current program.

Current Python 3 program consists of loading gpx tracks and optimising graph with four scans. Here's planned steps in my program:

1. Import points from gpx (working)
2. Join points located close to each other (working)
3. **Merge edges under small angles (Problem is with this step)**
4. Remove points on straights (angle between both edges is over 170 degrees). Looks like it is working.
5. Clean-up by resetting unique indexing of points (working)
6. Final checking of all edges in graph.

In my program I started counting steps with 0, because first one is simply opening and parsing file. Stackoverflow doesn't let me to start ordering from 0.

To store graph, I have a dictionary *punktid* (points in estonian), where *punkt* (point) object is stored at key uid/ui (unique ID). Unique ID is also stored in point itself too. Weight attribute is used in 2-nd and 3-rd step to find average of points while taking into account earlier merges.

```
class punkt:
    def __init__(self,lo,la,idd,edge=set(),ele=0, wei=1):
        self.lng=lo        #Longtitude
        self.lat=la        #Latitude
        self.uid=idd       #Unique ID
        self.edges=edge    #Set of neighbour nodes
        self.att=ele       #Elevation
        self.weight=wei    #Used to get weighted average
>>> punktid
{1: <__main__.punkt object at 0x0000006E9A9F7FD0>, 
 2: <__main__.punkt object at 0x0000006E9AADC470>, 3: ...}
>>> punktid[1].__dict__
{'weight': 90, 'uid': 9000, 'att': 21.09333333333333, 'lat': 59.41757, 'lng': 24.73907, 'edges': {1613, 1218, 1530}}
```

As you can see, there is a minor bug in clean-up, where uid was not updated. I have fixed it by now, but I left it in, so you could see scale of graph. Largest index in punktid was 1699/11787.

### Getting to core problem

Let's say I have 3 points: A, B and C (i, lyhem(2) and lyhem(0) respectively in following code slice). A has common edge with B and C, but B and C might not have common edge. C is closer to A than B. To reduce size of graph, I want to move C closer to edge AB (while respecting weights of B and C) and redirect AB through C.

Solution I came up with is to find temporary point D on AB, which is closest to C. Then find weighted average between D and C, save it as E and redirect all C edges and AB to that. [Simplified figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSNHQ.jpg) - note, that E=(C+D)/2 is not completely accurate. I cannot add more than two links, but I have additional 2 images illustrating my problem.

Biggest problem was finding coordinates of D. I found [possible solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64823/how-to-find-the-third-coordinate-of-a-right-triangle-given-2-coordinates-and-len) on Mathematica site, but it contains ± sign, because when finding coordinate there are two possible coordinates. But I have line, where point is located on. Anyway, I don't know how to implement it correctly and my code has become quite messy:

```
# 2-nd run: Merge edges under small angles
for i in set(punktid.keys()):
    try:
        naabrid1=frozenset(punktid[i].edges) # naabrid / neighbours
        for e in naabrid1:
            t=set(naabrid1)
            t.remove(e)
            for u in t:
                try:
                    a=nurk_3(punktid[i], punktid[e], punktid[u]) #Returns angle EIU in degrees. 0<=a<=180
                    if a<10:
                        de=((punktid[i].lat-punktid[e].lat)**2+
                           ((punktid[i].lng-punktid[u].lng))*2 **2) #distance i-e
                        du=((punktid[i].lat-punktid[u].lat)**2+
                           ((punktid[i].lng-punktid[u].lng)*2) **2) #distance i-u
                        b=radians(a)
                        if du<de:
                            lyhem=[u,du,e]  # lühem in English is shorter
                        else:               # but currently it should be lähem/closer
                            lyhem=[e,de,u]
                        if sin(b)*lyhem[1]<r:
                            lr=abs(sin(b)*lyhem[1])
                            ml=tan(nurk_coor(punktid[i],punktid[lyhem[0]])) #Lühema tõus / Slope of closer (C)
                            mp=tan(nurk_coor(punktid[i],punktid[lyhem[2]])) #Pikema     / ...farer / B
                            mr=-1/ml                                        #Ristsirge  / ...BD
                            p1=(punktid[i].lng+lyhem[1]*(1/(1+ml**2)**0.5), punktid[i].lat+lyhem[1]*(ml/(1+ml**2)**0.5))
                            p2=(punktid[i].lng-lyhem[1]*(1/(1+ml**2)**0.5), punktid[i].lat-lyhem[1]*(ml/(1+ml**2)**0.5))
                            d1=((punktid[lyhem[0]].lat-p1[1])**2+
                               ((punktid[lyhem[0]].lng-p1[0])*2)**2)**0.5 #distance i-e
                            d2=((punktid[lyhem[0]].lat-p2[1])**2+
                               ((punktid[lyhem[0]].lng-p2[0])*2)**2)**0.5 #distance i-u
                            if d1<d2: # I experimented with one idea,
                                x=p1[0]#but it made things worse.
                                y=p1[1]#Originally I simply used p1 coordinates
                            else:
                                x=p2[0]
                                y=p2[1]
                            lo=punktid[lyhem[2]].weight*p2[0]               # Finding weighted average
                            la=punktid[lyhem[2]].weight*p2[1]
                            la+=punktid[lyhem[0]].weight*punktid[lyhem[0]].lat
                            lo+=punktid[lyhem[0]].weight*punktid[lyhem[0]].lng
                            kaal=punktid[lyhem[2]].weight+punktid[lyhem[0]].weight #kaal = weight
                            c=(la/kaal,lo/kaal)
                            punktid[ui]=punkt(c[1],c[0], ui,punktid[lyhem[0]].edges, punktid[lyhem[0]].att,kaal)
                            punktid[i].edges.remove(lyhem[2])
                            punktid[lyhem[2]].edges.remove(i)
                            try:
                                for n in punktid[ui].edges:   #In all neighbours
                                    try:        #Remove link to old point
                                        punktid[n].edges.remove(lyhem[0])
                                    except KeyError:
                                        pass    #If it doesn't link to current
                                    punktid[n].edges.add(ui) #And add new point
                                    if log:
                                        printf(punktid[n].edges,'naabri '+str(n)+' edges')
                            except KeyError:        #If neighbour itself has been removed
                                pass               #(in same merge), Ignore
                            punktid[ui].edges.add(lyhem[2])
                            punktid[lyhem[2]].edges.add(ui)
                            punktid.pop(lyhem[0])
                            ui+=1
                except KeyError: # u has been removed
                    pass
    except KeyError:    # i has been removed
        pass
```

This is a code segment and it is likely to not run after copy-pasting because of missing variables/functions. New point is being calculated on lines 22 to 43, in 3rd if-statement from beginning `if sin(b)*lyhem[1]<r` to `punktid[ui]=..`. After that is redirecting old edges to new node.

Stating question clearly: How to find point on ray (AB), if two coordinates of line segment (AC) and angles at these points are known (angle ACB should be 90 degrees)? How to implement it in Python 3.5?

PS. (Meta) If somebody needs full source, how could I provide it (uploading single text file without registration)? Pastebin or pasting (spamming) it here? If I upload it to other site, how to provide link, if newbie users are limited to two?